# How to calculate student's average grade using HashMap?

Tags: java

In the Student class, I need to add a method to put a new course into the student's course collection and a method that calculates and returns the student's average grade. I keep getting "NaN" as a result when I try to calculate the student's average grade. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Below is my source code for the Student class.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;


public class Student extends Member
{
    // instance variables of class Student
    private HashMap<String, Double> courses;

    public Student()
    {
        super();
        courses = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param firstName
     * @param lastName
     * @param emailAddress
     * @param bcitId
     */
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String emailAddress, String bcitId)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, bcitId);
        courses = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    }

    public void addCourse(String course, Double grade)
    {
        if(!courses.isEmpty()) {
            courses.put(course, grade);
        }
    }

    public Double getAverageGrade()
    {
        Double averageGrade = 0.0;
        int counter = 0;
        if(!courses.isEmpty()){
            Set<String> course = courses.keySet();
            for(String grade : course){
                averageGrade += courses.get(grade);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return (averageGrade /= counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your method

```
public void addCourse(String course, Double grade)
{
    if(!courses.isEmpty()) {
        courses.put(course, grade);
    }
}
```

looks funny to me. Do you intend to only add a course if there is already at least one course in the map? This way, how will the first course enter the map?

I think you tried to check for the map to exist, but that would be done differently, namely:

```
if (courses == null){
  ...
}
```

About the division problem look at the other answer from Saposhiente. I would only repeat it...

Comment: Since he never added any courses to the map, this would also cause the NaN result.

Comment: Hence my suggestion to investigate Saposhiente's answer! Since this seems to be a homework assignment I think it is not asking too much of user3078337 to read a bit around.

Answer (score 2):

```
int counter = 0;
return (averageGrade /= counter);
```

NaN indicates division by zero, among other things. Counter was never incremented because no courses were added; see luksch's answer for why. Also, since you will never reference averageGrade again, you can simply use

```
return averageGrade / counter;
```

which is slightly more efficient.

Comment: It's more than forgetting to increment the counter; the code shows op did increment it. The problem is there's no check for when counter == 0 before the return statement.

Comment: `counter` is incremented. Rather, courses is empty so the OP is getting `0.0 / 0.0`.

Comment: Whoops, oversight. Edited. We now have two answers that each refer to the other; perhaps we should combine them into community wiki, hah.

Comment: good one. i would give you +1 for it, but i gave it already when i spotted your answer in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way it's going to return NaN is when the courses.isEmpty() returns true as the couter will not be incremented and you will divide by 0.

Also you could improve your cycle by using getValues()

```
public Double getAverageGrade()
    {
        Double averageGrade = 0.0;
        int counter = 0;
        if(!courses.isEmpty()){

            for(Double grade : courses.getValues()){
                averageGrade += grade
                counter++;
            }
        } else {
           return -1; // or some value that says that are no grades yet
        }

        return (averageGrade /= counter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a simple HashMap technique , refer the Below code for Caluclating 
**average** and find the **Beststudent** from it,Understand it well , I might help you 
Thanks...

```
import java.util.*;

public class QueQue {

public static float getAverage(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm, String name) {
    ArrayList<Integer> scores;
    scores = hm.get(name);
    if (scores == null) {
        System.out.println("NOT found");
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : scores) {
        sum += x;
    }
    return (float) sum / scores.size();
}

 // The best students from these Key-Value Pair

public static String getBestStudent(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm) {
    double max = 0;
    String beststudent = null;
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> x : hm.entrySet()) {
        String name = x.getKey();
        double average = getAverage(hm, name);
        if (average > max) {
            max = average;
            beststudent = name;
        }
    }
    return beststudent;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put("Peter", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);

    hm.put("Nancy", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Nancy").add(7);
    hm.get("Nancy").add(8);
    hm.get("Nancy").add(8);

    hm.put("Lily", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Lily").add(9);
    hm.get("Lily").add(9);
    hm.get("Lily").add(8);

    System.out.println("Find the average of the Peter");
    float num = getAverage(hm, "Peter");
    System.out.println(num);
    String name = getBestStudent(hm);
    System.out.println(name);
}

 }
```